# Windows cannot access the exe file generated by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I just packaged an app using PyInstaller, onedir mode. Then I encounter a weird problem. When I did it the first time, the exe file has no problem to open. Then I packaged a new version, I was never able to open the exe file again. The error is shown below. I searched quite a while online, but no solution found yet.

I'm using -

Windows 10

Python 3.8.2

Pyinstaller 3.6

[image: error pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `autopytoexe`. And within it select to export to one file. It solved that issue for me.

Comment: I kinda do it as onedir mode on purpose, because I want to make my app launch faster. I

Comment: Ok, can you show me the command with which you ran the pyinstaller?

Comment: sure. that is "pyinstaller --onedir --windowed --icon=icon.ico DataPal.py"

Comment: Ikleiv, somebody online said it is because of the icon setting, remove it should be fine, but I also need that icon.

Comment: Try without the icon. If that works with it then install that https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi and try to convert it with that program. Also please try to change the name of an icon - it might seem to be stupid, but sometimes naming something with the keyword name provides an error.

Comment: Thank you. I do it now.

Comment: I am trying using cmd instead of PowerShell,  make a new base folder, and changed the icon name, if it still doesn't work. I will try without icon. Then I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It failed. Next time I try without icon.

Comment: It is still not fixed yet. Maybe my python 3.8 has a conflict with pyinstaller 3.6. I'm downgrading to 3.6 now and will try again.@Aleksander Ikleiw

Comment: @GazZhao there are reported problems while you are using `python 3.8` because the structure was changed. The last fully compatible version is I believe 3.7

Comment: Thank you. Man. I downgraded to python 3.6. Now it worked.

Comment: @GazZhao no problem ;) I am glad that it is working if you could also upvote my answer it would be great :)